# How do I invert the scroll direction on a Google Graph?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, mousewheel

On a Google Line Chart like https://jsfiddle.net/j2jbLt9e/, how do I change the direction of the zoom? I want my graph to **zoom in** when I **scroll up** on the mouse wheel instead of zooming out (the default behavior).

According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#configuration-options), `explorer.zoomDelta` can be adjusted for zoom customizations, but inverting the default value of `1.5` leads to odd behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the zoomDelta to a value between 0 and 1 it will zoom in the "correct" direction.